# How to add two buttons in ajax modelpopup in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have been searching myself silly for this and can't find anything to help.
I want to add 2 buttons to my nav_menu one for register and one for login.
also i want it to popup with the ajax and can't seem to find that either.
I don't want to use the pages for registration or login.
Can somebody help me on this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this in a few ways. I would suggest using jquery/javascript to bind to those menu options and use jquery dialog to view the page in a popup.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    position: 'center' ,
    title: 'EDIT',
    draggable: false,
    width : 300,
    height : 40, 
    resizable : false,
    modal : true,
});

$("#loginOption").click( function() {
    $("#dialog").load('path/to/file.html', function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

jQuery Dialog Docs:  https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: yes, i have to do like this. but where i will define java script source file ?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) This is the error we are getting using a wordpress theme.

Comment: I would define this in the template file for your header, but its always recommended you put your JS in a .js file so it can be cached by the browser. The 404 is relating to the relative route called within $("#dialog").load('path/to/file.html', function() are you using the wordpress generated route or a page defined route?